# Query for "ACTIVE" users in LDAP server NOT working

Tags: active-directory, ldap-query

I need to be able to get via querying the active directory using the LDAP server a list of defined ACTIVE users from the active directory.

I have tried to do this via a successful connection to my ldap server.  In the java code below I get back ONLY 1 record when using the accountExpires attribute.  I should get back a list of records with each record displaying the DISPLAY NAME and MAIL attribute from the ldap server.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ADUserAttributes adUserAttributes = new ADUserAttributes();
    adUserAttributes.getLdapContext());
    adUserAttributes.getActiveEmpRecordsList("0", adUserAttributes.getLdapContext());
}

public LdapContext getLdapContext(){
    LdapContext ctx = null;
    try{
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "e~inventory"); 
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://xxxdc01.txh.org");
        ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
        System.out.println("Connection Successful.");
    } catch(NamingException nex){
        System.out.println("LDAP Connection: FAILED");
        nex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ctx;
}

private List<String> getActiveEmpRecordsList(String accountExpires, LdapContext ctx) {
List<String> activeEmpAttributes = new ArrayList<String>();
Attributes attrs = null;
try {
    SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
    constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    String[] attrIDs = {"displayname", "mail"};
    constraints.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
    NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("DC=txh,DC=org", "accountExpires=" + accountExpires, constraints);
    if (answer.hasMore()) {
        attrs = ((SearchResult) answer.next()).getAttributes();
        int empNameLen = attrs.get("displayname").toString().length();
        int empEmailAddrLen = attrs.get("mail").toString().length();
        activeEmpAttributes.add(attrs.get("displayname").toString().substring(13, empNameLen));
        activeEmpAttributes.add(attrs.get("mail").toString().substring(6, empEmailAddrLen));
        ctx.close();
    }else{
        throw new Exception("Invalid User");
    }
    System.out.println("activeEmpAttributes: " + activeEmpAttributes);
    System.out.println("count: " + activeEmpAttributes.size());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
return activeEmpAttributes;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for active UserPrincipals
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.Enabled = true;

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Comment: Marc - thanks for the additional info.  I was finally able to make my original query work.  Thanks for the link to the MSDN article.  Great info.  Appreciate your time.

Comment: @Melinda: please get in the habit of **accepting** the best answer provided, the one solving your problem. It's the right and polite thing to do on StackOverflow and serves as an incentive for others to continue to help those looking for answers. [See the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about)